# How to make layout like in image in android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: I want to make this type footer with clickable icons, how it can be possible.?]

I want to make this type footer with clickable icons, how it can be possible.?

Comment: Use image icons for the arrows and the home button, for the background red colour use an imageview and now for the buttons to embed in the imageview just refer these [tutorial 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211484/how-to-place-buttons-over-image-in-android), [Tutorial 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232546/how-to-create-a-button-on-top-of-imageview-and-align-it-to-the-bottom-of-the-scr)

Comment: Just create one layout in your `activity.xml` where you want such view. And set background color and three buttons and put this layout at bottom of your screen!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `Fragment` for this. All you would have to do is create a default layout (your buttons, the height and width of the fragment, the color of the fragment, and in the middle an `imageButton` that has its `background` set as a shape created in xml) Then all you would have to do is this:

```
android:drawableCenter="@drawable/ic_action_mic"
android:background="@drawable/default_button_style"
```

When each activity is created just load the fragment at the bottom, and you are done. Hope this helped!